# Can't figure out how to kill subprocess in Python 3.5

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm using Python 3.5.  I'm launching ffmpeg to record a file but I can't seem to kill the process.  I've tried this:

```
import os
import subprocess

pro = subprocess.Popen(recordcommand, shell=True)
...
do some things; wait for a stop command to come in 
...
if msg =='STOP':
     pro.kill()
```

My process starts fine but it never stops.  I do not get any errors.  I've checked the API and thought I was doing things right.  Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?  Thanks!

Edit:  Fixed pro.kill to pro.kill() but still not working.  Here's the command I'm sending:

```
 C:/Users/User/Desktop/ffmpeg-20150928-git-235381e-win64-static/bin/ffmpeg.exe -f dshow  -crossbar_video_input_pin_number 2 -i video="ATI AVStream Analog Capture" -f mpegts -fs 16777216 -y D:\Media\tvrecordings\SageSlingBox1onlocalhost4510TVTuner-0.mpgbuf 2>NUL
```

Perhaps something is keeping it from being killed?  I forgot to mention that my OS is Win 7 64 bit.

Comment: You are killing the parent process not the child i.e the shell. Not overly familiar with windows but passing a list of args with shell=False may work, if not you could taskill or   win32process

Comment: Thanks for this.  Unfortunately I'm a very novice 'programmer' .  Can you tell me how I kill the shell?

Comment: You are killing the shell, you need to kill the process. Try passing the args as individual args in a list and remove shell=True, if not just use check_call to kill ffmpeg with taskill if you want a simple solution

Comment: On Windows, you could [use `taskkill`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17614872/4279) or [`psutil`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25134985/4279).

Answer (score 1):

kill is a function, and as such has to be called to do anything.

Try changing it to:

```
if msg =='STOP':
     pro.kill()
```

Comment: afaik , iirc that will only work in *nix .. but yes that is certainly his issue (but it still might not kill the process ... , but that will be a different question +1 for this answer)

Comment: I made that correction but it still did not work.  I updated my question with additional information.  Thanks for the answer, but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

if you try to kill some process try this:

```
import subprocess
import sys
proc = subprocess.Popen(
['sudo', 'kill', args], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

proc.communicate(sys.argv[1])
```